# Ubuntu 16.04 ,redis Connection refused

Tags: redis

I am new to Redis.I have installed it from github repo.Now when I try

```
redis-cli
Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused
not connected>
```

With

```
ps aux | grep redis
milenko  14834  0.0  0.0  15444   980 pts/1    S+   11:14   0:00 grep --color=auto redis
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in your `ps` result, redis is not started yet (only the `grep` process is found).

You may want to start the service with a `redis-server` command.
Take a look at the documentation: https://redis.io/topics/quickstart#starting-redis